# docker-compose push a project into repository

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I have a problem / question what should I do when I have docker-compose.yml with several services and want to push this as a project into the repository.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

configs:
  prometheus_config:
    file: ./prometheus.yml
    
networks:
  inner_net:
    driver: overlay

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
        - 6020:80
    container_name: AVM.Core
    image: avmtemplate_app
  
  prometheus:
    image: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:latest
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    configs:
      - source: prometheus_config
        target: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    depends_on:
      - app
    container_name: Prometheus
  
  grafana:
    image : grafana/grafana
    depends_on: 
      - prometheus
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/data/:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./grafana/provisioning/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/
    env_file:
      - ./config.monitoring
    container_name: Grafana
```

As you can see, I have three services that depend on each other.
The "grafana" service depends on the "prometheus" service and this depends on the "app" service.

And this is what my "dockerfile" looks like:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 9090

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["../AVM.Core/AVM.Core.csproj", "../AVM.Core/"]
COPY ["../AVM.Domain/AVM.Domain.csproj", "../AVM.Domain/"]
COPY ["../AVM.Repository/AVM.Repository.csproj", "../AVM.Repository/"]
COPY ./prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
RUN dotnet restore "../AVM.Core/AVM.Core.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AVM.Core"
RUN dotnet build "AVM.Core.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "../AVM.Core/AVM.Core.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app/AVM.Core
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AVM.Core.dll"]
```

When I use *docker-compose up* i get three images and one project which include all this images. I Paste a screenshots that show it.

[image: List of images]

[image: Project which include this images]

Maybe some of you know how to push it into the repository so that a person who would like to use my template has to download only a project , and then she just launched the project to make it work? If this is not possible, what else should I do?

Thanks for all your answers

Cheers

Comment: Build your app image separately and push the image to a public repository. Then you can give someone your docker-compose file (i.e. have it in a github repo) and they can spin up all containers using only that. I think splitting it is good practice anyway, since building and running containers from the same docker-compose file confuses a lot of people.

Comment: @HansKilian Hmm, ok, but how do you establish the dependency between the containers? Now I have * depend_on in docker-compose: - app *, so when I create three docker-compose I will build three independ service so how do I tell them that this service depends on another?

Comment: You tell them by sharing your `docker-compose.yml` file.